# how to copy a file over ssh from a remote machine?(linux to windows)

Tags: ssh, putty

I am using putty to connect to a remote host and I wish to copy a folder containing multiple files from the remote machine to my local machine.I am on a windows machine and the remote machine is running linux.
Is there a GUI based tool available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I presume that you are invoking Putty on a Windows machine and using it to connect to some UNIX machine.

If that the case you cannot do what you want because putty is like a thin client giving you a terminal access.

I would suggest you to install `cygwin`  using which can help you with both the functionality of Putty and also allow you to use SCP.

Within `cygwin` you can do something like

```
scp -r  <user>@<remoteHost>:<pathtofile>/<fileName> <localfilename>
```

Comment: what is scp?
is there a GUI based ssh client available?

Comment: SCP is secure copy.

Comment: You can try using WinSCP a GUI based client for SCP. Its free and quite easy to use

Comment: What exactly worked ?

Comment: Note that if you installed puTTY, then you probably also have pscp (putty's scp version).

Comment: WinSCP worked...

Comment: @Hennes ...which is great but (last I checked) command-line only, and OP requested a GUI

Comment: Either I missed that, or the post was edited on 7-9-2013 at 6:17 (See http://superuser.com/posts/521413/revisions) and before that there was no GUI requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this, not sure if this will work using `putty`, but it's worth a try:

```
 ssh <user>@<host> cat /<path_to_file>/<filename> > <local_filename>
```

I just tried putty and the above will not work, but if you are running an `ssh` server on your windows machine I guess you would be able to do this:

1. Connect to the remote unix machine using: `ssh <user>@<host>`
2. Transfer the file from the unix machine using: `ssh <user>@<host> cat </path/file ">" filename`

You could also use `scp` if the program is installed:

```
scp <user>@<host>:/path/file <filename>
```

Look at this link: [Network File copy using SSH](http://daverdave.com/node/67)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest (in order of preference):

- SFTP through **[Filezilla Client](https://filezilla-project.org/)**. Available for Windows, Linux, OSX, in 34 & 64 bits. It works the best, deals with codepages, strange characters, autoretries connections, parallelizes transfers if possible, and works with some other protocols (FTP, SFTP, FTPS... etc). Just connect to:

  sftp://YourSSHServer
- **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** with [SFTP PlugIn](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm). Fails with some characters, but for sailing through directories is very useful. And... I LOVE the avesome Total Commander interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use putty and winscp in tandem.
If your server is behind a router first port forward the server so that putty can see the server from your internal network. Second configure putty to tunnel the server so winscp can connect to the server.

example:

server-ip:port(192.168.2.10:22)---router-port forward(22:192.168.2.10:22)---putty(router-ip:port)ssh tunneling(L3100:192.168.2.10:22)---winscp(localhost:3100)

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old post, but if you're using the Anniversary edition of Windows 10, another option would be to install the Linux Subsystem for Windows, and use scp or sftp within that.

Answer (score 0):

GUI solution is definitely filezilla or WinSCP. ;) Both are great. Filezilla is better at FTP in my experience, but I like the Norton Commander-style WinSCP interface more.  I think both should are GPL'd, but might include a payload of crapware you'll probably want to be careful not to install.

But since a lot of people are throwing out non-GUI solutions, suggesting you install OpenSSH tools native to Linux, I thought I'd mention my preferred non-GUI solutions. A fairly obvious lightweight solution is to use other tools that come with putty.

1) pscp

Similar to other explanations provided involving scp.  Comes with PuTTy installer, no need to install Cygwin or a Linux Subsystem for Windows.

2) plink

This is similar to using the ssh command on Linux. It does what PuTTy does, except in cmd.exe.

Example: plink user@host "cat file.txt" > file.txt

The example would stream file.txt on host to file.txt on client.

Really can't think of a major advantage to using plink for a simple download, but instead of streaming it you can pipe it elsewhere (not even bothering to save it) or process it some other way in addition to saving it (e.g., with tee).

I've used plink to get filter out log lines I don't need on the server side before straeming the parts I want to the client.  No need to download and save an intermediary file that way.